# two unequal lists showing equal python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to check if the two strings are anagrams or not.
But for the below code:

```
string1 = 'listen'
string2 = 'silena'
s1 = list(string1)
s2 = list(string2)
if (len(s1)!=len(s2)):
   print("Not an anagram")
else:
    if(s1.sort() == s2.sort()):
       print("it is an anagram")
    else:
       print("not an anagram")
```

python throws an output that the strings are anagrams.
For the if condition it is throwing the answer as true instead of False.

Comment: You may want to check what `sort()` returns.

Answer (score 5):

`list.sort()` sorts the list in place and returns `None`. So you are testing `if None==None`.

Perhaps you mean

```
if sorted(s1)==sorted(s2):
```

Also you can skip the lists entirely and have

```
if sorted(string1)==sorted(string2):
```